# EmguCV plugin for iSpy

Tags: c#, .net, emgucv

I'm trying to make a face recognition plugin for [iSpy](http://www.ispyconnect.com/) using the emgucv library. 

I've been trying for the past few days and I keep getting the [missing dlls error for CVInvoke](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Download_And_Installation#The_type_initializer_for_.27Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.27_threw_an_exception.) no matter what I try. The error comes up as soon as I try to use emgucv to generate an Image<> from a Bitmap the plugin receives from iSpy for each frame.

Any ideas on what can I do about it? 
All opencv dlls are where they are supposed to be and the required emgucv dlls have been added as references and being used.

The code is currently

```
public Bitmap ProcessFrame(Bitmap frame)
{
    Bitmap drawCopy = new Bitmap(frame);

    try
    {
        using (Image<Rgb, Byte> currentFrame = new Image<Rgb, Byte>(drawCopy))
        {
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(drawCopy);
        g.DrawString(e.InnerException.Message, new Font("Verdana", 8), new SolidBrush(Color.Tomato), 0, 0);
        g.Dispose();
    }

    return drawCopy;
}
```

ProcessFrame is the standard name for the method that receives the frame from iSpy.
Currently it prints the error message over the frame since debugging the plugin is impossible because it's not a stand alone application, it has to be a class library in order to be used by iSpy.

Thank you